# Connecting more than 100 ultrasonic sensors to a single Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: raspberry-pi, sensors, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core

I need help around creating a circuit of more than 100 ultrasonic sensors connected with a single Raspberry Pi(running on Windows 10 IoT core).

When IoT device sends request for Information(broadcast) to these sensors, response from all the sensors should go back to the Raspberry Pi. Then I should be able recognise the response sent by each sensor in my program.

I have studied a bit about I2C pins but not sure how to use it with my very limited electronics knowledge.

Comment: So you want to connect 100 sensors to Raspberry Pi using i2c bus?

Comment: Yes. But how to achieve it, I don't know. Or any other way would also be fine to me.

Comment: You can check "[I2C: How to connect multiple devices.](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=20852)" and [data sheet](https://github.com/raspberrypi/documentation/blob/master/hardware/raspberrypi/bcm2835/BCM2835-ARM-Peripherals.pdf).